# How to use JPA mapping /annotations if I am pooling two different types of values from only one column of single table.

Tags: java, jpa

I have 3 tables. LOV, SYS, and Rule. Sys table is mapped to View Controller of one of the editor in my application by using @Model. Now in editor I have to show 3 columns

1. App ID
2. Error message
3. Correction message

In sys table there is one column Char_value which holds AppID, and error message also.
In Lov table there is column called option value which holds correction message. 
so I wrote following queries to pull data

```
Query qAppId = em.createQuery("select osc from OscaSysControl osc "+
                    " where osc.oscaControlRule.categoryName ='PROBLEM LOG' and osc.oscaControlRule.controlName = 'APPLICATION ID'");


Query ErrCorr= em.createQuery("select osc from OscaSysControl osc join osc.oscaControlRule oscr " +
                    "left outer join osc.oscaControlLov lov " + 
                    "where oscr.controlName = 'ERROR MESSAGE' and oscr.categoryName = 'PROBLEM LOG' " +
                    "and oscr.processName = :processName");
```

I am making object of sys table as OSC because its mapped with VC so have to have everything in OSC. Also in second query I trying to get error and corr message in same result set. Passing process name as parameter.

res and res2 are type of SYS

```
res = qAppId.getResultList();
```

Following for loop is to pass the parameter to second query.  BUT ITS GIVING ERROR " SYS and String are not compatible "

```
List<String> appID = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for (OscaSysControl o : res) { 
    appID.add((String)o.getAppId()); // explain ?
}

int appIDLength = appID.size();
for (int i=0; i<appIDLength; i++){
    q2.setParameter("processName",appID.get(i));
    q2.setParameter("processName", res.get(i).getOscaControlRule().getProcessName());
    res2 = q2.getResultList();
    resultErrCorr.add((OscaSysControl) res2); 
}
```

CAN YOU PLEASE SUGGEST HOW DO I GO ABOUT MAPPING, ANNOTATIONS TO MAKE THIS WORK.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EclipseLink JPA implementation - there is a `@Convert`-Annotation, perhaps that will help. Had a similar complex problem where columns where joined by column name and bit values, the converter worked great.

How to use converters, see:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_(ELUG)#Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Converters